# Django admin register model for Many-To-Many relationships with extra fields and inheritance

Tags: python, django, inheritance, admin, blogs

Ok so I recently started with Django (and Python) so im a dummy.

Here is my Models (everything belows is in a same app) :

```
class Menulizable(models.Model):
    pass

class Category(Menulizable):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=155)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    short_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(Menulizable):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class News(Article):
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name="written_news")
    ...

class Page(Article):
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name="pages")
    ...

class Menu(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=155)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=155)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Menulizable, related_name='in_lists', through='MenuOrder')
    ...

class MenuOrder(models.Model):
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    gl = models.ForeignKey(Menu)
    gi = models.ForeignKey(Menulizable, related_name="menu_orders")
    ...
```

My goal is (in the admin panel /admin) to manage menus in which we can store a set of ordered objects which can be instances of Category or News or Page or Other objects (from child-classes of Menulizable).

My Admin :

```
class MenuInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Menu.items.through

class MenuOptions(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        MenuInline,
    ]

admin.site.register(Menu, MenuOptions)
```

Note that, this seems to work fine, this allows to manage menus in which we can set an ordered list of Menualizable objects.

The problem is :

[The **str** shown is the one of Menulizable instances and not the one of its child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dAQL.png)

I would like that appears in this list, at least the **str** of Article, Category instances, and not the **str** of Menualizable pseudo-abstract instances.

Anyone to help ? Am I clear or this is a mess ?

Thank you :)